# get token from spotify API using axios, error 404

Tags: axios, spotify

I`m trying to get the token from the spotify API, I use axios. I use the example given by the API as a guide, but give me the error 404

```js
export const getToken = code => async dispatch => {
    const responseToken = await axios.post({
        url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
        form: {
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code,
            redirect_uri
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
        },
        json: true
    })
    console.log(responseToken);
```

The first line is because I`m using redux,I just wanted you to see that it was a asinc method.

I have being all day trying to fix this, I don`t have more ideas of how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
form: {
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code,
        redirect_uri
    }
```

to

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code,
        redirect_uri
    })
```

You want to send it in the request body, hence "data", that's how you define it in axios.
Also, I don't think you need `json: true`

EDIT: 
Pretty sure you have to add `'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'` to the headers as well.